# how to show/hide div based on drop down selection using angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drop-down-menu

i want to show and hide a div based on selection from the drop down , here is my code, this is my html code for dropdown which fetches the values from the "selectItemsFilterCriteria" json structure

```
<select  ng-model="appointment" ng-change="changeme()"  ng-options="item.name for item in selectItemsFilterCriteria">
                <option ng-option value="" >Filter Criteria</option>
            </select>
```

this is my changeme() function created inside a controller

```
$scope.changeme = function() {
    $scope.appointment = $scope.items[0];
  }
```

this is code for my div that is to be show or hide , right now my code is working on selection of first option from drop down it is showing me the div but the problem is that its not hiding that div on the selection of any other option from the dropdown list, kindly tell me where i m doing wrong??

```
 <div class="mycontainer"  ng-show=appointment >
            <div class="left-nav">
                <accordion close-others="true">
                    <accordion-group ng-repeat="item in pagedItems[currentPage] |filter:{name:item.name}| orderBy:sortingOrder:reverse">
                        <accordion-heading>
                            <table>
                                <tr class="odd" ng-click="showDataDetail=!showDataDetail" style="cursor: pointer">
                                    <td><p class="lead-name">{{item.name}}</p>
                                        <p class="call-up-icon">{{item.phoneNo}} </p>
                                        <p>Lead Date : 07/02/2015</p></td>
                                    <td><p></p>
                                        <p class="blue-txt">{{item.trade}}</p>
                                        <p class="fl cstm-wdth">GNU09</p>
                                        <p class="fl">{{item.time}}</p>
                                        <div class="cb"></div>

                                    </td>
                                    <td><p>Today</p>
                                        <p>C#SQL</p>
                                        <p class="blue-remark-icon"></p></td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </accordion-heading>

                        <div>{{item.data}}</div>
                    </accordion-group>
                </accordion>
            </div>
        </div>
```

items array:

```
$scope.selectItemsFilterCriteria = [
    {id:1 , name:"Appointments Scheduled"},
    {id:2 , name:"fresh leads"}

  ];
```

Comment: Why you wanted to call the changeMe() function. Model is automatically updated when you change the option. Function call is unnecessary. Can you also provide the details of what is there in items array?

Comment: i am new to angular may b i donno whether its required or not , yes i am updating the items array

Comment: Can you provide the data in items array? Btw ng-change function is not needed.

Comment: i tried this is simply not working when i clicked fresh leads option then also i am not able to hide the div

Answer (score 0):

Basically the problem is with your ng-change function call,

```
$scope.changeme = function() {
  $scope.appointment = $scope.items[0];
}
```

You are setting **appointment** to **first value of items array**. Hence whenever you change the options, the function sets it back to first option , in turn the div is shown.

Please remove the ng-change function and try.

Comment: what should i change in ng-change function?? please specify?

Comment: Remove the function. It is not needed. Remove it both in the controller and in the template.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `$scope.changeme()` function. It is not necessary.

Since you are using ng-model on select whatever option you select will get assigned to the ng-model i.e **appointment** in your case.

Here is the plunkr [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/bHxAyxCOX3ckuROM23ZC)

Comment: thank you for the example i got your point but the problem i am facing here is of showing or hiding divs i have written it like this:                                <div class="mycontainer"  ng-show=appointment>                                           and it is working fine but how to hide it or show another div when i select another option ??

Comment: You can set a condition for appointment like `ng-show="appointment.id==2"`. This way you can specify when to show or hide div.